# Cron.hourly won't run

Tags: cron-jobs, command-line, crontab, cron

Ok, So I've made my script, I dropped it in `/etc/cron.hourly` then I `chmod 777` the file but it won't run (automatically). If I manually run it, it works fine. Do I need to do anything else?

Comment: This answer shouldn't have received that many upvotes without name of file and content.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Why not using crontab ( /etc/crontab ) and use */1 in the hour field. I have used this to run a script every 5 min and it works well:

```
# m h dom mon dow user  command
* */1  * * *   user    command
```

Comment: Using `cron.daily` and friends works a bit better if the machine is not running all the time, because anacron tries to approximate the right schedule whereas plain cron will just not run them if the machine is not on all night.  For hourly jobs this probably doesn't matter so much.

Comment: I really appreciate the next answer, as it addresses the problem with cron.hourly, rather than finding a workaround.

Comment: This is not an answer to the question

Comment: @poolie [As can be seen on `/etc/crontab`](https://askubuntu.com/a/519011/349837): `cron.daily`, `cron.weekly` and `cron.monthly`  run with anacron (if available) but hourly `run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly`.

Comment: Copy a script into specific directory or just delete it inside, it's much easier to deploy.

Answer (score 188):

Entries in `cron.hourly` are run by the run-parts mechanism ([`man run-parts`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/run-parts.8) for more info).  And `run-parts` is choosy about what filenames it considers valid.

For example, giving your script an extension will make it invalid and result in the job not being run. `[a-zA-Z0-9_-]` are the valid characters, so the '.' makes it invalid.

When adding a job to `/etc/cron.hourly` ( or `.daily`, `.weekly`, etc), always test afterwards that `run-parts` will actually run it by issuing the command:

```
run-parts --test /etc/cron.hourly
```

If by running this command it shows your file it means it worked. Otherwise, if doesn't show anything your file name is not valid.

What was the name of your script?

Comment: There are two: cerebro_random_response.sh and Cerebro Temperature.sh no good?

Comment: correct, no good :)  [a-zA-Z0-9_-] are the valid characters, so the '.' makes it invalid.  This is what i meant above by 'giving your script an extension will make it invalid'

Comment: oMG, This just saved a huge headache. THANK YOU! ```giving your script an extension will make it invalid and result in the job not being run```

Comment: You may also use `--report` to actually run the scripts.

Comment: Thanks for this info. My issue was that the script wasn't executable, `chmod +x /etc/cron.hourly/myscript` did the trick and `run-parts` listed it as expected.

Comment: That's pretty annoying, especially since `cron.hourly` directory has a dot in its name, which suggests that dot is okay

Comment: a fundmantal tenet of UX is "don't surprise the user". Why on earth would a . not be a valid character for something running under run-parts? What kind of incompetent developer makes such choices?

Comment: This works for me.

Comment: @Yvan you are correct. For others: please note, that `chmod u+x` is not sufficient even if root owns it and process is executed as root  it really has to be `chmod +x `

Comment: @JayEye ... especially, if naming is pointless and using hidden/dot files would be just enough and would work as expected, especially if even they use dotted file as a placeholder.

Comment: No file extensions are allowed inside this folder. Good trick :)

Comment: If the answer above did not solve your problem (you, viewer of this comment), I've aggregated a list of things to check that may help you: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/487471/307715

Answer (score 8):

DaithiF's answer should be the right answer.

Also, my script didn't have `#!/bin/bash` in the first line. Even though the script could be executed with the command line, `run-parts` rejected it saying "Exec format error".

Changing the file name from `scriptname.sh` to `scriptname` and adding the `#!/bin/bash` into first line enabled my script to run hourly.

Answer (score 5):

Your problem is probably down to the overly open permissions, which allows anybody to edit your file.  Try `755` instead.

Looking in the cron entries in your syslog output should confirm this.

Answer (score 2):

In my case I made these errors due to which `cron.hourly` wont execute my script:

1. I forgot to check if crond service is running: `systemctl status crond`
2. I haven't added new empty line in the very end of my script file like cron's scripts in other folders have.
3. I created my script file using WinSCP on Windows thus inserted Windows-like EOL symbol, which cron can't interpret correctly. So I needed to execute `sed -i -e 's/\r$//' /etc/cron.hourly/myscript` to fix it.

Answer (score -1):

When you run

```
crontab -l
```

is this task on the list?

if not, add it

```
crontab -e
```

add this line

```
0 * * * * yourScript
```

if it is in this list, try to add the path of programing language to the top of your script

Example:

```
bash: #!/bin/bash
```

This 2 things always solved my problems :)

Comment: Done it all and the script is good, it works like a charm. It's in the crontab list too but no hourly task runs. Thanks anyway :(